# SQL Query, select distinct, FROM, where or and

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table

```
Username    Client Name         Date        Time            Published App
1stLineS    GS-HPS7             03/08/2015   9:37:44.12     PB Service Desktop
1stLineS    GS-HPS7             09/07/2015  11:08:42.31     Citrix Delivery Services Console
1stLineS    GARION-WIN8         29/07/2015  15:34:19.85     menar@Work2-1
user1     009733-DSK          03/08/2015   9:41:56.25     Epic
user1     009733-DSK          03/08/2015  11:53:59.78     menar@Work2-1
user1     010175-LAP          06/08/2015   9:23:15.67     menar Desktop with Acrobat
user1     NC-CITRIXDESKAA     06/08/2015  12:54:23.51     Powerplan
user1     WT008064c025aa      13/08/2015  13:44:39.34     Thin Client Desktop
user2      NCIT-008888-DSK     25/07/2015   7:13:30.47     menar @ Work Desktop
user5     HTML-5190-7294      21/07/2015  11:23:03.42     menar@Work2-1
user6      005625-RMS          14/07/2015  14:22:17.37     menar@Work2-1
user7     008700-LAP          03/08/2015  12:31:35.12     menar@Work2-1
user8       004503-DSK          08/07/2015   9:10:30.71     menar@Work2-1
user9   010030-LAP          03/08/2015  11:32:34.53     menar@Work2-1
user10       ABBY-PC             03/08/2015  13:59:25.21     GLH Contractors Web Portal
user3       009899-IT           10/07/2015  18:07:49.17     PB Service Desktop
user3       MEMBER-PC           11/08/2015  19:37:49.94     RDP NC-BACKUP01
user11      005240-LAP          03/08/2015  11:43:23.43     menar@Work2-1
user12      008617-DSK          03/08/2015   8:44:32.54     menar@Work2-1
user13    HP81017347825       02/08/2015  16:07:48.10     menar@Work2-1
user4    009178-DSK          03/08/2015   9:07:03.91     menar@Work2-1
user4    009178-DSK          07/07/2015  10:58:33.74     menar Desktop with Acrobat
user4    009178-DSK          07/07/2015  10:59:33.74     epic
```

I need to get back user where they have Mencap@Work2-1 and a "desktop published app", which is a specific set of apps, im specting back this list of users

```
1stLineS
user1
user2
```

I dont get spected results...

I've tried the following query(s) and Returns 0

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%Menar@Work2-1%\"
AND publishedapp LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
AND publishedapp  LIKE \"%RDP%\"
GROUP BY username


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username, publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp = \"Menar@Work2-1\"
  AND publishedapp   NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
  AND publishedapp   NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\"
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT publishedapp) > 1
";
```

I've tried with more variations, but to be honest I dont know what im doing any more I'm a bit brain dead

Comment: Show us your current query, and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Don't store dates and times as separate entities. Just store them using a proper datetime data type.

Comment: why the down vote still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT username,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT publishedapp SEPARATOR \"<br>\") AS publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp LIKE \"%Menar@Work2-1%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%@%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
OR publishedapp LIKE \"%RDP%\"
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT publishedapp) > 1 AND
SUM(DISTINCT publishedapp LIKE \"%Menar@Work2-1%\") > 0
```

not only returned the list of users it returned a string with the list of apps used, like this

```
1stLineS
  Menar@work2-1
  Citrix Delivery Services Console
user1
  Epic
  Menar@Work2-1
  Powerplan
user2
  Menar@Work2-1
  Epic
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `having` clause and `group by`:

```
SELECT username
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY username
HAVING SUM(publishedapp LIKE '%Mencap@Work2-1%') > 0 AND
       SUM(publishedapp LIKE '%Desktop%') AND
       SUM(publishedapp LIKE '%RDP%');
```

Comment: I probably didnt formulate the question correctly. Having did point me on the right direction. so thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp REGEXP 'Mencap@work2-1|Desktop|RDP'
GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: This returns me when published app contains one or the others... not what im looking for...

Comment: This would give you the username having the required publishedapp SELECT DISTINCT Username
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp REGEXP 'Mencap@work2-1|Desktop|RDP';

Comment: required? Is not, what i require, this gives me if it has any of thoose there I need to get if they have Mencap and any other...